# How to express the second derivative of $f^{-1}$ in terms of $f'$, and $f''$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have this excercise:

"let $y(x)$ be a function, in $x\in (a,b)$ exist the inverse function $x(y)$. If $y(x),  x(y)$ have 2 derivatives in their definition domain, by $y´(x), y´´(x)$ express:
$$\dfrac{d^2x}{dy^2}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) says: if $f$ is continuously derivable and has a non zero derivative at $x$ and $y=f(x)$ then $$(f^{-1})'(f(x))=\frac{1}{f'(x)}.$$
Take the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$. Then we get
$$(f^{-1})''(f(x))f'(x)=-\frac{f''(x)}{(f'(x))^2}.$$
That is,
$$\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}=(f^{-1})''(y)=-\frac{y''}{(y')^3}.$$
(If the second derivative exists as well.)